# Вычислить количество повторяющихся пар в столбце

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Необходимо вычислить количество повторяющихся пар в столбце `name`:

```
d = {'name': ['rick, mike, morty', 'tot, piter, carl', 'brick, nick', 'rick, reaven, bart, homer', 'rick, morty'],
     'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', '9/30/2009'],
     'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'EU', 'BY']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Ответ должен выглядеть как:

| name | inp |
| --- | --- |
| rick, morty | 2 |

Нет ли другого выхода, кроме как использовать функцию `for` и `combinations`? Ну, или хотя бы без for)

Comment: "повторяющаяса пара" это что?

Comment: Это два значения в ячейке, находящиеся не обязательно подряд, и имеющиеся в других ячейках вместе (не обязательно подряд).

Comment: А если встретится не пара а тройка?

Comment: Можно и тройка.

Comment: Я пока что не вижу как это без циклов сделать. Накидал функцию, которая дает список имен которые входят 2 и более раз. Нужно?

Comment: Пришлите, посмотрим) Сравню со своим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вместо цикла for можно использовать встроенную функцию map, примерно так:

```
from itertools import combinations,chain
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

d = {'name': ['rick, mike, morty', 'tot, piter, carl', 'brick, nick', 'rick, reaven, bart, homer', 'morty, rick'],
     'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', '9/30/2009'],
     'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'EU', 'BY']}
c = Counter(chain(*map(lambda x: combinations(sorted(x.split(', ')),2), d['name'])))
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': c.keys(), 'inp':c.values()})
df = df[df.inp>1].set_index('names')
```

вывод:

```
              inp
names   
(morty, rick)   2
```

Answer (score 2):

Это не полный ответ. Пример кода, который дает список повторений 2 и более раз.
На его основании можно построить правило отбора...

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'name': ['rick, mike, morty', 'tot, piter, carl', 'brick, nick',
              'rick, reaven, bart, homer', 'rick, morty'],
     'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014',
              '12/20/2020', '9/30/2009'],
     'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'EU', 'BY']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
#добавим новый столбец, в котором строку с именами преобразуем
#в лист с именами
df['lists_name'] = df['name'].str.split(',')

def get_list_repeats_name(arr):
    #arr - серия из списка списков
    list_name = [y for x in arr for y in x]
    set_name = set(list_name)
    return [x for x in set_name if list_name.count(x) >= 2]

print(get_list_repeats_name(df['lists_name']))

>>>['rick', ' morty']
```

Answer (score 1):

C помощью коллективного разума решение найдено):

```
d = {'name': ['mike, rick, morty', 'tot, piter, carl', 'brick, nick', 'rick, reaven, bart, homer', 'rick, morty'], 'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', '9/30/2009'], 'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'EU', 'BY']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df['name'] = df.name.str.split(',\s*')
df['gr'] = df.name.apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2)))
df = df.explode('gr')
df['gr'] = df.gr.str.join(',')
display(df.gr.value_counts().index[0])
```

Спасибо за посильное участие!